# How to get the noise variance from the Stochastic Variational Gaussian Process (SVGP) in GPFlow

Tags: gpflow, gaussian-process

As the question states I'm wondering how to get the noise variance (not the signal variance) from the SVGP model in GPFlow.
To clarify, by noise variance I mean the parameter of the Gaussian likelihood, which I understand to be the difference between the predictive variance of observations minus the predictive variance of the latent function (the latter is what I meant by signal variance).

The SVGP is not actually my aim, I'm trying to understand the heteroscedastic model, but that also uses SVGP so I thought I'd start there.

Comment: Hi! could you clarify what exactly you're looking for? Do you mean the parameter of the Gaussian likelihood? Or the predictive variance of observations at test points ?

Answer (score 0):

The likelihood object is stored in `model.likelihood`. For the exact Gaussian process regression model (implemented in `gpflow.models.GPR`), this is always a `Gaussian` likelihood, and you can access the noise variance using its `likelihood.variance` attribute. So if you defined your model as follows,

```py
model = gpflow.models.SVGP(kernel, gpflow.likelihoods.Gaussian(0.01), inducing_variable, ...)
```

then you can access the current value (after optimization) using `model.likelihood.variance`.

Or `model.likelihood.variance.numpy()` if you want it as a numpy type -- this will be a scalar (0-dimensional) array, and you can retrieve its value as a standard Python float using `model.likelihood.variance.numpy().item()`.

For the heteroskedastic model, one GP parametrizes the mean, the second the variance, so you can simply use the prediction for the second GP (and then you have to pass it through the link function you're using).

Comment: Thanks, that helped clarify things. With the link funciton you mean the HeteroskedasticTFPConditional? One confusion I had was that I did not fully grasp wether the predicted variance of the second GP was only the variance of the noise function. When looking at the latent functions with predict_f I saw that it gave back two means and two variances. Am I right in understanding, that the first mean and variance are the mean and variance of the signal and the second mean represents the noise variance with the second variance representing the variance of the prediciton of the noise variance?

Comment: By link function I mean the `scale_transform` attribute of HeteroskedasticTFPConditional, which takes the second GP (which is unconstrained between minus and plus infinity) and transforms it into a strictly positive quantity (as required of a variance). Note that this makes it non-Gaussian.